# Special characters are stored as ? in my mysql DB

Tags: php, mysql

I use the following code to store and update data in my db.

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8", true);
mysql_connect("localhost", "test", "test") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("test") or die(mysql_error());

    // mysql_set_charset('UTF8');
    mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
    mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
    mysql_query("SET COLLATION_CONNECTION = 'utf8_unicode_ci'");




    mysql_query("UPDATE `test`.`english` SET age = '".$age."', city = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['city'])."', aboutMe = '".$_REQUEST['about']."' WHERE `english`.`username` = '".$_REQUEST['username']."' LIMIT 1 ;") 
    or die(mysql_error());
```

The code is working well. But if the string, e.g. "city" contains a ä,ö,ü it is stored as ?
So for example the word "Bär" goes to "B?r".

I have already added these utf8 things but it does not help.
The server is only supporting php4.x

Edit: The DB is using latin1_general_ci as collation.

Comment: The PHP version is not the problem here, the issue is how MySQL is storing these values.

Comment: Try this query first: `alter table `test`.`english` convert to character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci;`

Comment: I tried it but now the ä ü ö are ignored and also the character after it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use utf8 as collation, maybe `utf8_bin` or `utf8_unicode_ci`

(The ci means it's case insensitive so comparsions like "John" = "JOHN" return true).  You can do this by running the following query in MySQL:

```
alter table `test`.`english` convert to character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: Thx, I tried it to change it to utf8_unicode_ci and now the ä ö ü are not stored. So a word "Bücken" -> "B". I have only added the collation to one row!

Answer (score 0):

change the table collation to `utf8_bin`.

To change the default character set and collation of a table including those of existing columns (note the convert to clause):

```
ALTER TABLE tableName CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin
```

in `utf8_general_ci`

```
ä = a
ö = o
ü = u
```

but in `utf8_bin`

```
ä != a
ö != o
ü != u
```

Comment: utf8_general_ci is a legacy collation that does not support expansions, contractions, or ignorable characters. It can make only one-to-one comparisons between characters.

Comment: The strange thing is. I have another table with the same collation latin1_general_ci and it works with ä ü ö, why?

Comment: That would be my recommendation, especially if case doesn't matter to you when comparing.

Comment: I changed it to utf8_unicode_ci. Now it ignores the special characters as ö. So a word like Bär -> B

Comment: Do I have to change it for the whole table like in the suggested query above or only for the row?

Comment: I changed the whole table to utf8_bin. It still does not work. "hhüüh"goes to "hh"

Answer (score 0):

Keep ut8_unicode_ci and add this to your php code:

```
mb_language('uni');
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
mysql_query("set names 'utf8'",$connection);
```

I am using this everywhere (Cyrillic, Chinese etc ) and it is working for every query (insert or update).

```
 <?php
        header("Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8", true);
        $connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "test", "test") or die(mysql_error());

        mb_language('uni');
        mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
        mysql_query("set names 'utf8'",$connection);

        mysql_select_db("test") or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_query("UPDATE `test`.`english` SET age = '".$age."', city = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['city'])."', aboutMe = '".$_REQUEST['about']."' WHERE `english`.`username` = '".$_REQUEST['username']."' LIMIT 1 ;") 
        or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Make sure that is your database, your table and your column has utf8_general_ci Collation and you page also utf8.

Comment: How do I ensure this for all of these ?

Comment: In phpmyadmin you have Operations tab for db, and table. You will see Collation drop down.  In table you click on Change for some column at you will see Collation drop down. You just select utf8_general_ci and click save (Go button in Operations, and Save button in table chnage). .

Answer (score 0):

I got it working. I have no explanation for this behavior.
I have changed in the php file from utf8 to latin1:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'latin1'");
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET latin1");
mysql_query("SET COLLATION_CONNECTION = 'latin1_general_ci'");
```

In the MySQL DB the collation is utf8_unicode_ci for the table and column.

It is working now for all characters beside the € symbol.